# Sorting with single stack and switch arguments in java

Tags: java, switch-statement, stack

I am trying to write 2 methods that can sort a string of brackets using only 1 stack and 1 switch statement. I can't get it to work, I am wondering if it may be because of cases of ' ' in strings? should not default case pick up these or have I understood switch statements wrong? This is where I am right now.

```
out.println(checkParentheses("({} [()] ({}))"));  // should print true 
                                                                
out.println(!checkParentheses("({} [() ({)})"));  // should print false 


Boolean checkParentheses(String brackets) {

    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();


    for( char ch : brackets.toCharArray()) {
        if (stack.peek() == matching(ch)) {
            stack.pop();
        } else {
           stack.add(ch);
        }
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}


char matching(char ch) {
    // char c = (' ');
    switch (ch) {
        case ')':
            return '(';  // c = '('
        case ']':
            return '[';
        case '}':
            return '{';
        default:
          // return c;
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("No match found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging or at least running your code?  Or you'd prefer SO community do it for you?  Line `if (stack.peek() == matching(ch))` throws NPE immediately because you do not check if stack is empty; method `matching` throws IllegalArgumentException if an opening bracket/parenthesis is found.

Comment: Also `!checkParentheses("({} [() ({)})")` cannot return `false`, because there is logical NOT `!`operator and the result for the given input is definitely `false` - the string is not apparently balanced, so here `! false -> true` should be expected.

Comment: sorry, shouldve mentioned that but yes i did both run and debug, and it simply said "variables not found". now that you mention it its really obvious that it also rejects on opening brackets.

Answer (score 1):

1. Non-bracket characters should be ignored in the input, optionally the input may be cleaned out of them or just skipped quietly
2. Special checks for opening/closing brackets need to be implemented.

Basically, `checkParentheses` should be as simple as follows:

```java
public static boolean checkParentheses(String str) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (openingBracket(c)) {
            stack.push(c);
        } else if (closingBracket(c)) {
            if (stack.isEmpty() || matchingBracket(c) != stack.pop()) {
                return false;
            }
        } // else ignore non-bracket char quietly
    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

Then additional methods may look as follows using `switch` statement:

```java
static boolean openingBracket(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '(': case '[': case '{': case '<':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

static boolean closingBracket(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case ')': case ']': case '}': case '>':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

static char matchingBracket(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case ')': return '(';
        case ']': return '[';
        case '}': return '{';
        case '>': return '<';
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad character found instead of closing bracket: " + c);
    }
}
```

Then the output of the tests is as follows:

```java
System.out.println(checkParentheses("({} [()] ({}))"));  // true, balance ok
                                                                
System.out.println(!checkParentheses("({} [() ({)})"));  // true, NOT balanced
```

Comment: thanks! this looks much more thorough. isnt there anyway to implement openbracket into matchingbracket somehow? for example letting default represent all open brackets? ofcourse also have to handle " " in cases expr = "({ })" maybe that isnt possible in switch statements, i have never worked with them before so are trying to learn.

Comment: methods `openingBracket` and `matchingBracket` have different purpose and return type.  `openingBracket` is needed to define if the current char should be pushed to the stack.